# How do you update some variable in a bundle using webpack and Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, bundler, webpack-5, nrwl-nx

We have declared a variable in a file that should be replaced by an object during compilation.

```
declare const I18N_MAP: Record<string, string>;
```

While bundling the files using webpack we hash certain files using WebpackManifestPlugin.

```
new WebpackManifestPlugin({
  filter: (filter) => {
     return filter.name.startsWith('assets/i18n/");
  },
}),
```

This will create a ison file in the dist directory.
The constant `I18N MAP` should be replaced with this content.

How would you do that or is there a better approach to this?

We tried using a custom webpack plugin that runs after the manifest file is created in order to add a variable to the index.html

```
<script>
const I18N_MAP = {...}
<script>
```

```
 apply(compiler: Compiler): void {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('HtmlReplacementPlugin', (compilation) => {
      compiler.hooks.emit.tap('HtmlReplacementPlugin', ( ) => {
        Object.entries(this.options.replacements).forEach(([key, replacement]) => {
          const replaceWith = this.getReplacementValue(replacement, compilation.assets); // look for compilation.assets["manifest.json"]
          if (!replaceWith) return;

          this.replaceHtmlPlaceholder(compilation, key, replaceWith); // look for compilation.assets["index.html"]
        });
        
      });
    });
  }
```

Using nx build `compilation.assets["index.html"]` doesn't exist.
It works when using dev-server with nx serve.

The process should also work during development when the files are located in memory. So we can't rely on using the file system only.